# Using terser or alternative to minify and uglify js files

Tags: javascript, npm, minify, uglifyjs, terser

I have a simple web project with one big javascript file (ES6)
i want to minify and uglify it so it will be harder for others to obtain it

After a bit of searching i found [terser](https://github.com/terser/terser)

and i've been using it in the following way

```
terser originalFile.js --compress --mangle --output result.min.js
```

when i come to examine the output file created i do notice that its minified (no white spaces) but its not uglified in fact doing auto format to it returns it to the original and readable state

how can i uglify my file without using webpacks or anything like this

Thanks

Comment: Terser did mangle your function and variable names, for more you need to use more Terser settings: https://github.com/terser/terser